# Moment show only time part if same day else show full date time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Looking for some simplified solution to show only time part if same-day else show full date time

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
function format(val) {
   return val.format('YYYYMMDD') === moment().format('YYYYMMDD') ? val.format('HH:mm') : val.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'); 
};

console.log(format(moment("2020-12-31")));
console.log(format(moment("2021-01-01")));
console.log(format(moment()));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Depending on what the current date is, this example will show the date together with the time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `isSame` method from momentjs to check if the date equals current date by passing in either `day` or `date` as its parameter

```js
let input = moment("01/01/2021 10:00:00", "MM/D/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
let result = moment().isSame(input, "day")
  ? moment(input).format("h:mm:ss")
  : moment(input).format("DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss");
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/moment@2.29.1/min/moment.min.js"></script>
```